# Why does my compiled .exe of C++ file shows an error that does not ordinarily appear?

Tags: python, c++, command-line

Today, I just created a typing meteorite project. I thought it would be great to simply call `system("py -3.8 wait.py 0.1");` in C++ to wait for 0.1 seconds. It was successful in normal execution in visual studio code, but when I execute the compiled .exe file, it repeatedly shows that the file `wait.py` does not exist, which is false in my scenario.

Any help regarding the problem will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure it exists somewhere on your hard drive, but the question is: does it exist in the current directory?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, it does exist on my current hard drive.

Comment: That’s an awfully complicated way of writing `std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);

Comment: @PeteBecker My <thread> does not exist... This should be a story for another day.

Comment: @IanChiang - The fact it exists on your hard drive is irrelevant.   Sam's point is that it doesn't exist in your program's current working directory.   Python does not scan your entire hard drive to find a file it is given on the command line - it looks in a specific place (or maybe a set of specific places).   If a full path is not specified, the default place is the current working directory.   And the `system()` call typically means the launched program inherits the working directory from the program that called `system()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a absolute path for call wait.py !

For example:

`system("py -3.8 C:\Users\wait.py 0.1");`